# compute the cycle of a recursion

Tags: number-theory

Let $ x_0=1 , x_{i+1}=2x_i $ be a recursion over $\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z} $ , $m=2^n*r$ and $h$ be the order of $2 $ modulo $r$. Now compute the cycle of this iteration and its tail!

We have $ 2^h=1 \mod r $ right? The sequence is $\{ 1,2,4,8,... \}$ so we have $x_i=2^i \mod m$

When $m=2^n*r$ is reached we start from $0$ again. But when h is such that $2^h=1 \mod r$ what does that mean for the number $ 2^h*r = k*r+1 \mod n $ for a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

So the Iteration is $ \{ 1,2,4,...,2^{n-1}*r,1,2,4,... \} $ am I right?

Is this right what I concluded here? Now what's the tail of this Iteration?

Comment: "$t_{1, 2}$" makes no sense because $t_{n,k}$ is defined only for $k\le n$.

Answer (score 3):

Look at some data, and you’ll see that what you have is not right. I assume that $r$ is odd and greater than $1$. For $r=3$ and $n=0,1,2,3$ you get the following sequences, with the repeating cycle underlined and copied out to the right:

$$\begin{array}{rl|rr}
n=0:&\underline{1,2},1&1&2\\
n=1:&1,\underline{2,4},2&2&4\\
n=2:&1,2,\underline{4,8},4&4&8\\
n=3:&1,2,4,\underline{8,16},8&8&16
\end{array}$$

For $r=5$ and $n=0,1,2,3$:

$$\begin{array}{rl|rrr}
n=0:&\underline{1,2,4,3},1&1&2&4&3\\
n=1:&1,\underline{2,4,8,6},2&2&4&8&6\\
n=2:&1,2,\underline{4,8,16,12},4&4&8&16&12\\
n=3:&1,2,4,\underline{8,16,32,24},8&8&16&32&24
\end{array}$$

For $r=7$ and $n=0,1,2,3$:

$$\begin{array}{rl|rrr}
n=0:&\underline{1,2,4},1&1&2&4\\
n=1:&1,\underline{2,4,8},2&2&4&8\\
n=2:&1,2,\underline{4,8,16},4&4&8&16\\
n=3:&1,2,4,\underline{8,16,32},8&8&16&32
\end{array}$$

And for $r=9$ and $n=0,1,2,3$:

$$\begin{array}{rl|rrr}
n=0:&\underline{1,2,4,8,7,5},1&1&2&4&8&7&5\\
n=1:&1,\underline{2,4,8,16,14,10},2&2&4&8&16&14&10\\
n=2:&1,2,\underline{4,8,16,32,28,20},4&4&8&16&32&28&20\\
n=3:&1,2,4,\underline{8,16,32,64,56,40},8&8&16&32&64&56&40
\end{array}$$

Compare the length of the repeating cycle with $h$, and note how the repeating cycle for $2^nr$ is related to the repeating cycle for $2^0r=r$. There’s more than enough data here for you to spot the patterns, and once you’ve identified them, proving them is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Do you realize you are a genius?